# As a reviewer, should I act when the second reviewer did not seem to review the manuscript carefully?

Tags: peer-review

I reviewed a manuscript and suggested a major revision, which was done in meantime. Now that I receive the revised manuscript again, I see that the 2nd reviewer wrote only one sentence in his review to the first draft of the manuscript, although there were major issues at the theoretical, methodological, and linguistic levels. Should I tell the editor that I consider such a review insufficient?

Comment: Strictly spoken, it's not your job, but the editor's. I remember writing detailed reviews when my co-reviewers wrote very shallow ones with the opposite opinion. They were chastised by the editor. You may consider highlighting it to the editor so that their attention is directed to the matter and not by chance overseen.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs How did you know they were chastised?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I saw the comments, they were visible to the other reviewers. That was probably good, because I wrote several pages and that reviewer hardly a paragraph, with a very decisive opinion opposite of mine. I would probably have felt a tinge of my time being not properly appreciated if I hadn't seen the editor take action. Imagine that reviewer's suggestion being followed without comment?

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Interesting, I haven't ever received comments on my review (although I've only done a handful)

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Perhaps you did a good job :-)

Comment: I agree that it is neither my job nor my responsibility to judge on other reviews. I am convinced that the editor is also aware of the issue (because reviewer #2 only wrote that the paper is well written). Perhaps I also feel even more responsible for the quality of the article because my name and reviews are published with the article, whereas Reviewer #2 has chosen to remain anonymous. The authors have for the most part responded to my criticisms, but we all have our blind spots.

Comment: Basically your review should account for this. Obviously you can't spot troubles with review B that you haven't already spoke out in your review. Far from perfection, but that's why there are at least two referees for serious publications.

Comment: Follow-up: I approached the editor in a separate message, and he told me he's usually compensating for bad reviews by reading the paper more carefully himself.

Answer (score 15):

> I see that the 2nd reviewer wrote only one sentence in his review to
> the first draft of the manuscript, although there were major issues at
> the theoretical, methodological, and linguistic levels.

Are these issues not addressed in the revised submission (based on your comments)? Have the authors addressed all your comments carefully and satisfactorily?

> Should I tell the editor that I consider such a review insufficient?

I would not do this. It is the job of the editor to see whether the reviewer has done justice to the article.

---

However, if you think there are still some issues with the revised manuscript, give it a fresh read and add more comments, e.g.

"I can see that the authors have addressed all of my previous comments. But, I still see that the article could be further improved if the following few points are addressed..."

Comment: "It is the job of the editor to see whether the reviewer has done justice to the article."  That might make sense in this case, where it is obvious, but in situations where the assessment of a peer review requires special technical knowledge, the editor asking a peer reviewer for feedback on a peer review is appropriate and does happen.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Yes, absolutely. My statement only focused on the present case of OP. As you said, sometimes the editor has to take help of a peer-reviewer; but, isn't it rare though?

Answer (score 9):

I suspect that the editor has also recognized this and I doubt that your reinforcing it will have any effect. But yes, you can pass on your observations. There may be valid reasons for the "failure" of the other reviewer (or not).

But it seems as if the paper got improved, so the system as a whole hasn't failed.

Comment: The fact that the paper has improved does not necessarily mean that the system hasn't failed. It could still have major flaws, which is why as many people as possible must read the manuscript carefully.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this kind of response as an editor - reviewer A says reviewer B's review is terrible because of so-and-so. I was certainly not offended, and neither was reviewer B, because I never shared reviewer A's comments with reviewer B.

So it's OK. In your case though, "I consider their review insufficient" is not something for you to judge; what is sufficient or insufficient is for the editor to decide. A technical comment such as "reviewer B's ___ comment is not appropriate because ___" would be more useful to the editor. Furthermore, in your case, it might not be necessary to tell the editor at all, because it should be obvious that the second reviewer's review is superficial.

Comment: I agree it is ok. Keep in mind that it is possible that the comment does end up with reviewer B, depending on where you put it (if you directly send it to the editor all may be fine, but if you put it in your review it may end up with the other reviewer in one way or another). So word your comments carefully.